# Unknown IP addresses/providers used by PC: How to make sure no system-wide VPN/proxy is active?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, proxy

When I visit websites of services like http://whatismyipaddress.com on my PC, it regularly shows an IP address (a different address per session) which has nothing to do with my Internet service provider, which is suspicious.

Now, I know that:

1. It does not depend on the browser, because I installed a second browser and the IP stays the same (unknown to me) on that browser as well.
2. It does not depend on the router, because on a second PC, I see that an IP of my Internet Provider is used (which is what both PCs are supposed to do).

Although I have a couple of VPN connections configured in Ubuntu's "Network Connections", I do not explicitly activate any of them on the WiFi connection I use. And Ubuntu's WiFi connection icon doesn't show the VPN-lock either.

In "All Settings/Network", I also see that no "Network proxy" is configured.

Could I somehow have set up a VPN connection (or something similar) that is automatically activated, but not visible to me? How/where could I check that? Is there a general way to see how the OS "chooses its IP"?

(Or do I have to conclude that I am hacked?)

---

EDIT: Added the requested terminal output below.

```
$ ifconfig
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:8c:fd:4a:d4:7a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:47191 (47.1 KB)  TX bytes:47191 (47.1 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.14.0.24  P-t-P:10.14.0.24  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fdda:d0d0:cafe:1300::1016/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:271347 (271.3 KB)  TX bytes:43422 (43.4 KB)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.14.0.28  P-t-P:10.14.0.28  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fdda:d0d0:cafe:1300::101a/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:1c:a8:fa:4c:fb  
          inet addr:192.168.1.108  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cdb8:13c7:9e68:cae4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:410
          TX packets:582 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:372815 (372.8 KB)  TX bytes:139225 (139.2 KB)
          Interrupt:17 


$ iwconfig
tun0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

tun1      no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"<my_wifi_name>"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 5C:49:79:6C:1D:43   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for <my_user_name>: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:8c:fd:4a:d4:7a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 44:1c:a8:fa:4c:fb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.108 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:b1100000-b1107fff
```

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have an extension enabled in your web browser, can you disable all the extensions in your web browser to make sure that's not what's going on?

Comment: Thanks, but I can exclude that point, because the second browser (freshly installed, no extensions) shows the same IP (which is unknown to me).

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Comment: @heynnema - I have added the info you requested.

Comment: Notice the devices tun0 and tun1... those are VPN tunnels. You probably have VPN set to autostart in your network script. Pull down the network icon and select `Edit Connections`. Click on `Wired Connection` or the appropriate wireless script, and check for VPN options. Your VPN provider may have also provided an application which is in your `Startup Applications` that starts the VPN.

Comment: @heynnema - Thank you. The connection I use didn't have its ```Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection``` checkbox checked. But to be sure, I have a) deleted the connection I use, b) deleted all VPN configurations in ```Network Connections```, c) rebooted the PC, d) re-created the deleted connection, but the IP/provider is still unknown to me. And in ```Startup Applications```, I only have a SSH Key Agent...

Comment: Do you still see the tun0 and tun1 devices? Exactly where do you see the IP address of concern, and what is that address?

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to `@heynnema` for the help which lead me to my specific solution:

Although I had deleted all VPN configurations in `Network Connections`, their `*.conf` files were still present in `/etc/openvpn` (not sure if this is a bug or my mistake).

And since I had not explicitly uncommented the commented out line `AUTOSTART="none"` in `/etc/default/openvpn`, OpenVPN assumed "please autostart all" (referring to the above mentioned `*.conf` files).

Therefor, I simply had to delete all `*.conf` files in `/etc/openvpn` for the unwanted VPN connection(s) to go away.

From now on, I will simply use the VPN provider's client, which I suppose is less error prone for average users.